# How do you access under a front loading washing machine drum to remove a trapped coin?

Tags: repair, kitchens, appliances, washing-machine

We had a coin trapped under our front loading washing machine drum (found out after it was removed).

The washing machine engineer got it out by prising the lip of the inside of the drum upwards, pulled out the coin, then bashed the edge of the drum back down with a metal wrench. This has now left the drum dented and the enamel scratched. I am currently in the process of complaining and getting the damage caused rectified.

Was this the only way he could've removed the coin? The scratches are now going to cause rust and potentially rip delicate clothing. It looks horrible too. See picture below.

[image]

Secondly, what is the best way to fix the damage that has now been caused? Can it be repaired or is a new drum/machine required?

Comment: The shop should have quoted you for full drum removal in order to preserve things in their pristine state and only offered you the current method as an extremely cheap fix if you found proper repair to be too expensive and could tolerate the cosmetic damage. Having metallic detritus loose in the washing machine and the subsequent damage caused is not a warranty repair. By their nature, front loaders are prone to debris getting trapped like this.

Answer (score 1):

There is certainly a method for removing/replacing the drum.  Most newer models have exploded parts diagrams online, both by the manufacturer and third party appliance part vendors.  The vendors frequently have videos (hosted on YouTube). You can google them by using the washers model number.

As far as fixing the rim damage, one of the rotary tools, like Dremel, would make short work of making it smooth. Start with a metal grinding bit and finish with buffing wheels loaded with buffing compounds.

The dented section (above the rim in your picture) should not cause clothing damage, it just ugly.

I doubt the drum will rust, as its likely stainless steel throughout.  Any paint damage (not seen in picture) that is scratched through the topcoat, should be primed and painted with automotive or appliance grade products.

I hope you get satisfaction from the shop.  This damage was careless and unnecessary.

Do know that a full drum removal would have been quite expensive, due to the number of labor hours needed

Answer (score 1):

Your washing machine engineer was careless. Removing the drum usually isn't that hard and shouldn't any damage to the drum. It definitely doesn't require hammering.

I have had to remove the drum on three different Kenmore washing machines and one dryer. I have removed a coin and a screw, and I have replaced a number of other components within the washing machine. Obviously, the devil is in the details, and your machine may require vastly different steps then mine.

Beforehand, I located and consulted the parts diagram, found a tutorial for my model on repairclinic.com and ordered the parts online. Once the parts arrived I went to work.

Ours is a stacking washer/dryer, so my wife and I first had to remove the dryer from the top. If yours is also stacking, the repair engineer may have wanted to avoid this step.

After this, the process generally involves removing two top screws, top tabs, and two bottom screws from the face of the washing machine, removing the face (or the top), and gaining access to the interior. From here I could easily remove objects from the interior, remove another side (like the top or the front), replace the filter, reposition the drum, replace the pump, etc. Some things were easy to do and others were more difficult.

Each time this took less then an hour, and it got easier each time.

Unplug the washer first, since there may be some open circuits within the machine.